# HTML JavaScript CSS - Parallax Issues with outsourced code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my issue that I have right now is that I've created an HTML page with a parallax effect with a menu that moves with the page. Creating a sort of fixed menu browsing the page.

I ran into some issues while trying to continue the project. The menu itself I believe should blur out the pictures behind it whilst it covers it, however, what I've noticed now is that my other texts & boxes shine right through the menu.

This is my project on GitHub: https://github.com/oksmantv/HTML_Page_Public/tree/master

This is the original script/code from https://codepen.io/Oksmantv/pen/PooyGyJ. It consists out of 3 parts, CSS, JavaScript & HTML. This below is the JavaScript part

```
var $content = $('header .content')
  , $blur    = $('header .overlay')
  , wHeight  = $(window).height();

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  wHeight = $(window).height();
});

window.requestAnimFrame = (function()
{
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

function Scroller()
{
  this.latestKnownScrollY = 0;
  this.ticking            = false;
}

Scroller.prototype = {

  init: function() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), false);
    $blur.css('background-image',$('header:first-of-type').css('background-image'));
  },


  onScroll: function() {
    this.latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY;
    this.requestTick();
  },


  requestTick: function() {
    if( !this.ticking ) {
      window.requestAnimFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
    this.ticking = true;
  },

  update: function() {
    var currentScrollY = this.latestKnownScrollY;
    this.ticking       = false;


    var slowScroll = currentScrollY / 2
      , blurScroll = currentScrollY * 2
      , opaScroll = 1.4 - currentScrollY / 400;
   if(currentScrollY > wHeight)
     $('nav').css('position','fixed');
   else
     $('nav').css('position','absolute');

    $content.css({
      'transform'         : 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      '-moz-transform'    : 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      '-webkit-transform' : 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      'opacity' : opaScroll
    });

    $blur.css({
      'opacity' : blurScroll / wHeight
    });
  }
};


var scroller = new Scroller();  
scroller.init();
```

To illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image: Example]

So here I am asking you what it is, that doesn't make this tick!

Comment: Did you try to add z-index to the navigation?

Comment: When you are posting a question in StackOverflow, kindly expecting you to just mention the question. Any other stories or thanking statements will confuse the users who are referring question. Always try to keep your question short and understandable.

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind. I'm super fresh to all of this